# Border goes outside div

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem with a div which goes outside the parent element (div.navigation-view).

index.html

```
<div class="navigation-view">
    <div class="nav-content">
        
        

    </div>
</div>
```

navigation.sass

```
$nav-bar-height: 50px
$nav-bar-link-color: white


body
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    
div.navigation-view
    background-color: black
    height: $nav-bar-height
    width: 100vw
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    
    div.nav-content
        display: inline-block
        height: 100%
        max-height: 100% !important
        width: 60%
        border: 1px solid red
```

Image:

[Image with border going outside the other div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3aMN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add box-sizing: border-box to your styles:

navigation.sass

```
*
    box-sizing: border-box
```